# apollo usequery causes undefined errors

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a fairly simple component:

```
import {useQuery} from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import resolvers from '../../resolvers';

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const {data} = useQuery(resolvers.ReturnAllMovies);
  const movies = data?.movies;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DashboardMovieOverviewMenu />
      { movies?.length > 0 ? <MovieOverview /> : null }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default DashboardComponent;
```

Issue here is that `usequery` loads the component twice, but the first time it's being loaded the `data` is undefined. So if want to check if the const `movies` has any movies in it I get an error that `movies` is undefined. Which makes sense since the data has not loaded yet. I resolved the issue using the `?` syntax to do a null check, but there has to be an easier way right? Or should I check if loading is true/false in each component?

Comment: If you just want to render an empty list without many checks, set sane defaults: `const { data: { movies = [] } = {} } = useQuery`. Now `movies` is available right away as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loading`. while making API call data will be `undefined`. and `loading` set to `true`. this works without adding `optional chaining(?)`. but its recommened to keep `?`

```
import {useQuery} from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import resolvers from '../../resolvers';

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const {data, loading } = useQuery(resolvers.ReturnAllMovies);
  if(loading){
   return "Loading...";
  }
  const movies = data.movies;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DashboardMovieOverviewMenu />
      { movies?.length > 0 ? <MovieOverview /> : null }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default DashboardComponent;
```

this doc explains clearly how you can handle loading and error cases -> [executing-a-query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query)

Comment: That's quite annoying.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma just different states **in time**, `data` undefined at start, usable after loading (next render) - clearly explained in docs/tuts

Comment: I understand that, but it's still annoying that you have to do null checks etc to catch it.

Comment: no null checks required - just data-ready checks (`!loading` or `if(data)` or `data &&`)